# jQuery ajax requests repeats when error occurs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've read through several posts related this this kind of issue, but I'm still not identifying the issue here.

When the following function is called and receives a 200 response, all is well; when it encounters 404 the ajax is repeated; adding a timeout only limits the time frame during which the repeat requests are made. There has to be a simple reason for this, but it is eluding me ...

```
function myFunction(ID) {
    var url = 'http://example.org/' + ID;
    var response;
    $.ajax(url, {
        success: function (responseText) {
            if (responseText !== undefined) {
              response = responseText;
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, errorMsg) {
            if (xhr.status == 404) {
                console.log('404: ' + errorMsg);
            } else if (xhr.status == 401) {
                console.log('401: ' + errorMsg);
            }
        }
    });
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Please provide the code from where you are calling your function.

Comment: You probably have a condition to repeat requests if you get a 404. Post the code from which you call myFunction()

Comment: `return response;` is the problem

Comment: `response` will likely return `undefined` on a few occassions because the ajax call is async. That's another error OP should fix.  However I don't think it would cause the function to repeat requests continuously. That must come from a higher function that uses myFunction() and keeps calling it till it gets a response of 200.

Comment: Thanks for prompting me to look elsewhere for the problem. Part of the issue was that, in fact, the function was being called more than once in different parts of the code, and I was able to address that issue independently. But @shakti-phartiyal was also helpful, see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below given approach to get the data for your error without repetition in AJAX.

```
$.ajax(url, {
    success: function (responseText) {
        if (responseText !== undefined) {
          response = responseText;
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        //the status is in xhr.status;
        //the message if any is in xhr.statusText;
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

You cannot return the response because you have an **async** request and response variable will be returned before the actual ajax requests gives a response. So I suggest You either use a callback function on success ore use a synchronous request.

So to get the response you can have a function like so:

```
function getResponse() {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: your_url,
        async: false
    }).responseText;
}
```

Or the callback approach is:

```
$.ajax(url, {
    success: function (responseText) {
        if (responseText !== undefined) {
            theCallbackFunction(responseText);
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        //the status is in xhr.status;
        //the message if any is in xhr.statusText;
    }
});

function theCallbackFunction(data)
{
    //do processing with the ajax response
}
```

Comment: What makes this work but OP's code fail? They seem almost identical

Comment: @MatthewCiaramitaro Any specific reasons for the downvote please ??

Comment: I didn't down vote, though I will note your answer has improved since I commented and you had two downvotes at one point but are now at a net of 0

Comment: In fact I'm 12 reputation points from being allowed to downvote

Comment: @MatthewCiaramintaro does my answer help you out ??

Comment: Thanks for this! I did review my code and adopted the callback approach as described. I also tried the `async:false` approach, but it yields a warning message that this is deprecated due to adverse impact on user experience.